# compute function in stereomatcher opencv - get disparity

Tags: opencv, nvidia, disparity-mapping

I am newbie to opencv. I am looking to understand steromatcher class compute function and stereoSGBM class compute function.

I am following this example,
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html

```
Ptr<StereoBM> left_matcher = StereoBM::create(max_disp,wsize);
wls_filter = createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher);
Ptr<StereoMatcher> right_matcher = createRightMatcher(left_matcher);
```

createRightMatcher function returns StereoBM or SteroSGBM pointer.

```
left_matcher-> compute(left_for_matcher, right_for_matcher,left_disp);
right_matcher->compute(right_for_matcher,left_for_matcher,right_disp);
```

Left_matcher compute function takes only 20ms.  But the right_matcher compute function takes 320ms.  I am not sure to get the disparity, what is the significance of the steromatcher class compute function.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am running this Nvidia Tx1

Comment: setting the number of disparity in negative.  will take more time?  Since In the right image data is shifted in negative directive in the left image